# How to terminate a call programmatically under Android?

Tags: android

I am using the following code for dialing programmatically under Android.

```
try {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
} catch (Exception exception) {
    log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", Exception);
}
```

But how can I terminate the call programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You can't terminate in progress calls programatically.