# Lock Android Phone after user dials a phone number

Tags: android

I am developing a security application whereby, if a user dials a phone number that is not frequently called and he has never called before, the user will have to reauthenticate himself. For this purpose I want to lock the phone after checking the phone number.

```
public class outgoingCalls extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.v("onReceive", "In onReceive()");
    if (confidence == 0) {
        Log.v("onReceive","confidence zeroed");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("abc.xyz.SECURITY","abc.xyz.SECURITY.lockActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } 
}
```

In this new Activity lockActivity, I need to lock the phone where I have commented // LOCK PHONE

```
public class lockActivity extends Activity {  

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    Log.v("lock","lockActivity onCreate method called");
        //  setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        Log.v("lock","locking");
// LOCK PHONE
}
}
```

The phone is not getting locked with the methods I have tried. These include the following:

```
1.  KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager)   getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock("edu.Boston.SECURITY.lockActivity"); 
((KeyguardLock) lock).reenableKeyguard(); 

2.  PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
manager.goToSleep(100);//int amountOfTime

3. PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,    "Tag");
wl.acquire();
wl.release();

4. WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
   params.screenBrightness = 0;
   getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Android manifest file has below permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Why am I not able to lock the phone? Any pointers? 
Thanks a lot in advance for your help. Appreciate it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820307/how-to-terminate-a-call-programmatically-under-android - Someone stated that it is not possible to terminate in progress calls. Is that true ? Could that be the reason I cannot lock the device or atleast terminate the call?

Comment: we can terminate the dialed call using **setResultData(null)**.

Comment: Is this the 'don't call your ex drunk' kinda app? :D

Comment: Thanks Sahil, I am trying your suggestion. Shark - No,lol - but i am sure that can be one good use!haha

Comment: @user1773209 :-if possible, please share your answer.

Comment: check [this][1] post 

might help............

:)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793339/lock-an-android-phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a DevicePolicyManager

http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/device-management-policy.html

and then call:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM  = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM.lockNow();
```

Comment: Teknogenie - That worked somewhat.. in my case when i make a call then the screen goes black and the screen seems to have been locked but i cannot see the locked screen for unlocking.. when i click on the lock button on top of my phone then it unlocks and proceeds to make the call. Still debugging.. but thanks a lot for your help and getting me this far! Thanks!!

Comment: I just found that what is happening is that the call is still being made but the phone is getting locked after the call is ended. So it worked, i just need to possibly place the code the right place to interrupt the call and to end the call..